# How can I order by match result in doctrine querybuilder?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a custom dql match function and would like to select the match result as 'score' before ordering by that score. How can I adjust the following query to achieve this?

```
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb
        ->select('i', 'bi')
        ->from('AdminBundle:Items', 'i')
        ->where('i.instock=1')
        ->leftJoin('AdminBundle:MyTable','bi',\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'i.id = bi.productId')
        ->andWhere('bi.productId IS NULL')
        ->andWhere('MATCH (i.brand, i.store, i.title, i.description, i.keywords) AGAINST (:search BOOLEAN) > 0')
        ->andWhere('i.instock = 1')
        ->setParameter('search', $searchString)
        ->setMaxResults( $limit )

    ;
    $results = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Answer (score 4):

I do not know if I understand your question, do you want to add to your select what you have in your where (match...) and order by it?

You can add not-mapped selects like this:

```
$qb->addSelect('MY_FUNCTION(my.params) AS HIDDEN mySelectAlias')
```

In your case, sth like:

```
$qb->addSelect('(MATCH (i.brand, i.store, i.title, i.description, i.keywords) AGAINST (:search BOOLEAN)) AS HIDDEN mySelectAlias')
```

And in your order by:

```
$qb->orderBy('mySelectAlias', 'desc');
```

Complete example: 
https://coderwall.com/p/o5snag

Comment: Thanks, and yes thats what i want to do. Can you explain what you mean by not mapped and also if its possible for score not to be hidden so i can include it in my results?

Comment: I used "mapped" to reference those fields that have a declared mapping between database and PHP, that is those fields that Doctrine will hydrate (that fields that have an equivalent in your entity). 

To write that "match" into an entity, I suppose you could try hydrating arrays instead of entities or hydrating custom entities that include both, your entities + your new field (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#new-operator-syntax), but it's only an idea because I've never had that case.